# Kafka NotLeaderForPartitionException

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to create a simple Kafka Client that i am running from a Springboot application.  My requirement is to use Kafka 0.8.2.2 version.  The application works fine in the beginning then I am getting this exception I am unable to find the root cause.

In the Kafka log I see following exception:

Offset request with correlation id 0 from client testgroup on partition [TESTQA,2] failed due to Leader not local for partition [TESTQA,2] on broker 256
2017-07-21 03:40:54,186 INFO kafka.network.Processor: Closing socket connection to /.

```
kafka.common.NotLeaderForPartitionException: null
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor41.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at kafka.common.ErrorMapping$.exceptionFor(ErrorMapping.scala:86) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.earliestOrLatestOffset(SimpleConsumer.scala:169) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread.handleOffsetOutOfRange(ConsumerFetcherThread.scala:60) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2.jar:na]
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread$$anonfun$addPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:177) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2.jar:na]
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread$$anonfun$addPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:172) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2.foreach(Map.scala:130) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.addPartitions(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:172) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2.jar:na]
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherManager$$anonfun$addFetcherForPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherManager.scala:87) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2.jar:na]
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherManager$$anonfun$addFetcherForPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherManager.scala:77) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2.foreach(Map.scala:130) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherManager.addFetcherForPartitions(AbstractFetcherManager.scala:77) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:95) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:60) [kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 5):

NotLeaderForPartitionException is logged at the ERROR level with a full stack trace. But really this is just an informational message on the server when a client with stale metadata sends requests to the wrong leader for a partition.

visit : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-816

Comment: OK, can you elaborate a little? what is the consequence from the client's perspective of this exception? what happens to the request sent? what should we do to avoid that message? how can we ensure that we are connected to a partition lead?